# How can i implement rowspan to a a specific cell in itextsharp pdf in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview

I have a requirement to  export data from gridview to pdf. I am using itextsharp to achieve this. However i have trick situation  on  which i have to show data as grouped if the values are the same in some cells. I am ble to the grouping in gridview but unable  to reproduce the grouping in itextsharp pdf. Thus, i want to changed a rowspan to more than 1 if the values are the same in row cells. For example if cell 1 in row 1 and the same value as in cell1  in row 2 then there should be no repeat of this value but only rowspan for cell1 in row1 should change and span to 2 rows. How can i chieve this using itextsharp to export to pdf?

Comment: What have you done so far? Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many exaples of yousing rowspan in ITextSharp http://forums.asp.net/t/1953696.aspx?how+to+create+a+pdf+with+rowspan+and+colspan+:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

Document doc1 = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 42, 35);;
FileStream fs1;
PdfWriter wri1;
fs1 = new FileStream("C:\\1.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
//Create Document class object and set its size to letter and give space left, right, Top, Bottom Margin
wri1 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, fs1);
doc1.Open();
PdfPTable t = new PdfPTable(4);
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("RepGroup Logo")) { Rowspan = 9 });
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CID")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CID-Val")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ven Logo")) { Rowspan = 9 });
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CPO")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CPO-Val")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Order Status")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Confirmed")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Order Date")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("10/02/2013")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ship Date")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("12/01/2013")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Back Orders")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Accepted")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ship Via")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Best Way")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Terms")));
t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("CC")));
doc1.Add(t);
doc1.Close();
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "acroRd32.exe"; //not the full application path
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\1.pdf";   // "/A \"page=2=OpenActions\" C:\\example.pdf";
myProcess.Start();
```

Other links: [Rowspan or nested? Create a table itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872060/rowspan-or-nested-create-a-table-itextsharp), http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/colspan-and-rowspan.